# Bootstrap 3 + Rails Application Change lineheight form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am changing the login form and have been struggling to change the line-height. I have tried the following options:

1. Add a class to the individual elements (e.g. Email)
2. Add a class to the form
3. Combine 1. & 2.
4. Add a div element to each individual part.
5. Add a name to each element.

I can change pretty much anything, except for the line height (and width). This seems to be a common issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Add top and bottom padding instead.

Comment: but will that change the individual height of the form? I need to make the "email" password etc bigger

Comment: Just target only the inputs you need by adding unique class.

Comment: What do you want? Bigger input?
Can you provide us an HTML sample please (JSFiddle, Bootply, ...) that allow us to better understand your needs?